# Facebook like box not allowed additional query string from wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook-like, query-string

I am unable to share wordpress page with my custom query string in facebook like box using facebook api. for example http://www.example.com/?page_id=10&myquery=10 after hit like button "myquery=10" is removed from above url, only we are getting "http://www.example.com/?page_id=10" in my wall.

Thanks&Regards,
Arunabathan.G

Comment: Can you provide us a link for the page? Do you have an `og:url` tag on your page? If so you should remove it (since it's forcing the share to an incorrect location) and use the facebook url debugger (former url linter) to clear the url cache and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the canonical URL you've set your page to.

### How to discover the problem?

If you check out [your URL on the facebook url debugger tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://breakbounce.com/lookbook/?slideID=4), you'll see that the fetched URL if the url with the querystring (http://breakbounce.com/lookbook/?slideID=4), but the canonical URL does not have the querystring (http://breakbounce.com/lookbook/).

---

### Where does this comes from?

This problem can be originated by two meta-tags, either `og:url` is defined to a different URL or a `<link rel="canonical" ...>` is defined (being the last one your problem, view your page souce and search your code for `<link rel='canonical' href='http://breakbounce.com/lookbook/' />`)

---

### How to fix it?

In a normal situation you need to alter or delete the tag you identified as problematic on the previous step.
In you case you need either to change or delete the `<link rel='canonical' href='http://breakbounce.com/lookbook/' />` tag.

**Importante Note:** After changing or deleting the tag you'll need to visit the [facebook URL debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) again and enter your URL, in order to clear the cache of your url from Facebook.

---

Anything let me know.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot. i got solution form your reply. (http://pixelpunk.co.uk/2010/01/disable-wordpress-built-in-canonical-url/) reference for remove canonical url via wordpress function

Answer (score 0):

You can also fix it like this:

```
http://www.example.com/?page_id=10%26myquery=10
```

the **%26** is an equivalent for the ampersand. I had this problem when I tried additional parameters in a query, and this worked for me :)